# Why does a query using a parameter return no rows when the same query with constants returns 122K

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm in SQL Server 2008 and I have been working on making some older code use parameters instead of building the queries using string concatenation. And I'm also working on making things work faster by doing things like adding indexes to tables.

The table I am working with has many columns (it's the heart of a star schema reporting database) and has more than 4M rows.  The create for the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rptTransaction](
    ...
    [Date] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
...
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Yes, the date column is poorly named because it collides with a keyword. They *are* using string dates [remember it's a reporting database].

When I execute the following code in MS SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @testDate NVARCHAR  = N'2012/03/01';

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM rptTransaction AS t 
 WHERE t.Date >= @testDate
       AND t.Date <= @testDate
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
GO
```

The results are as follows:

```
(No column name)
0
```

On the other hand when I execute the following code:

```
DECLARE @testDate NVARCHAR  = N'2012/03/01';

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM rptTransaction AS t 
 WHERE t.Date >= N'2012/03/01'
       AND t.Date <= N'2012/03/01'
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
GO
```

The result is the following:

```
(No column name)
124888
```

(I am using the OPTION (RECOMPILE) because otherwise the parametrized version does a full table scan, which takes a long time.)

Comment: Please don't store dates as varchar types, even for reporting databases.

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT count(*) FROM rptTransaction WHERE [Date]=N'2012/03/01';`? Same query, but with the parameter?

Comment: Also, if you must use character types, why nvarchar? The date column should **never** have any wide characters, so nvarchar would be safe here, as well as use less storage and give faster queries when filtering or matching on that column. And since everything should all be same length, why even let it vary? Just use `char(10)` or again, even better, `date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this code:

```
declare @testDate nvarchar = N'2012/03/01';
select @testDate ;
```

One my system, the output was just `2`.

Try this instead:

```
declare @testDate nvarchar(10) = N'2012/03/01';
select @testDate ;
```

Much better:

> 2012/03/01

That's one of two unexpected parts of your query. The other is that you required your value be *both* >= ***and*** <=. In other words, the only way to satisfy the query is if the parameter matched your stored data exactly. `2` is never going to do that if the column is all valid dates.

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar by default uses a length 1.specify the length say 10 in  this case